# convert ordinary web project to silverlight supported application

Tags: .net, silverlight, web

I have a dotnet web solution. I wish to include the silverlight technologies into it.
Can you tell how do I proceed.

I am new to silverlight...so might be this question a blunder :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install the Silverlight SDK (if you don't have it already) and create a new Silverlight project. This project should contain the Silverlight application and a web project containing sample code on embedding it. You may also take a look at [this site](http://silverlight.net/learn/).

Comment: In silverlight we have inbuilt popups...if i add a silverlight application to current web project...is it necessary to have a WCF to display the contents of popup when user click popuplink.?

Comment: It depends on what your application is doing and where's the data coming from.